# Avoiding the for loop using dataframes in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in Python named `GroupedCode` (70000 rows and 3 columns) and `ICD9` (11500 rows and 27 columns). My goal is to find every element in `Code9` column of `GroupedCode` that is present in the `ICD9CMCode` column of `ICD9` and every time that I find a match, append the value of the `TotalDiag` column of the `ICD9` into a list called `Freq`.
I came up with a For loop to do this but it takes a good amount of time to complete. I was wondering if there is a better way to speed up the for loop or even better avoid it.

Here is my for loop:

```
Freq = []
for code in GroupedCode.Code9:

if (len(ICD9.TotalDiag[ICD9['ICD9CMCode'].str.match(code)]) == 0):
    Freq.append(0)
else:
    Freq.append(ICD9.TotalDiag[ICD9['ICD9CMCode'].str.match(code)].values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [merging](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two data frames to retain matches between each other then downcasting pandas Series to a [list](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html). Currently, you are storing numpy arrays (not single values) or 0 to a list.

```
merged_df = pd.merge(GroupedCode, ICD9, left_on='ICD9CMCode', right_on='Code9')

Freq = merged_df['TotalDiag'].tolist()
```

Even consider [`unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) for unique values in case of multiple inner join matches.

```
Freq = merged_df['TotalDiag'].unique().tolist()
```